# Oracle / OWB: Specifying the partition for INSERT at runtime

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-partitioning, oracle-warehouse-builder

(Background: we're running a data warehouse built with Oracle Warehouse Builder. Recently, we started getting a lot of "ORA-02049: distributed transaction timeout while waiting for lock" errors. The reason for this is that we're running several ETL jobs in parallel, and each of these jobs does a `INSERT /*+APPEND PARALLEL*/` into our staging table. This staging table is partitioned by the source system ID. )

I'd like to know if it is possible to specify the partition key for an INSERT at runtime.
Suppose I have a table

```
create table tmp_loading_table (
  etl_source_system_fk number not null enable,
  object_id number not null enable,
  object_name varchar2(30) not null enable
)
  PARTITION BY LIST ("ETL_SOURCE_SYSTEM_FK") 
 (PARTITION "ESS1"  VALUES (1), 
 PARTITION "ESS2"  VALUES (2)  
);
```

then I can insert into a specific partition using

```
insert  /*+ APPEND PARALLEL("TMP_LOADING_TABLE") */     
into tmp_loading_table partition(ESS1) (
  etl_source_system_fk, object_id, object_name)
(select 1 etl_source_system_fk, object_id, object_name from user_objects);
```

but this requires me to hard-code the partition name.

Since our OWB mappings are generic (they get the source system ID as a parameter), I'd like to provide the partition name at runtime, something like

```
insert  /*+ APPEND PARALLEL("TMP_LOADING_TABLE") */     
into tmp_loading_table partition(:partition_name) (
  etl_source_system_fk, object_id, object_name)
(select 1 etl_source_system_fk, object_id, object_name from user_objects);
```

Is this possible? If not, is there another method to achieve this with Oracle Warehouse Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`PARTITION FOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements009.htm#i165979) syntax and dynamic SQL can help.

Ideally it would be this simple:

```
declare
    v_partition_value number := 1;
begin
    insert  /*+ APPEND PARALLEL("TMP_LOADING_TABLE") */     
    into tmp_loading_table partition for (v_partition_value) (
      etl_source_system_fk, object_id, object_name)
    (select 1 etl_source_system_fk, object_id, object_name from user_objects);
end;
/
```

Unfortunately the above code fails with `ORA-14108: illegal partition-extended table name syntax`.  Which is strange since that seems like an obvious use
for that syntax.

Adding dynamic SQL removes the error.

```
declare
    v_partition_value number := 1;
begin
    execute immediate '
    insert  /*+ APPEND PARALLEL("TMP_LOADING_TABLE") */     
    into tmp_loading_table partition for ('||v_partition_value||') (
      etl_source_system_fk, object_id, object_name)
    (select 1 etl_source_system_fk, object_id, object_name from user_objects)';
end;
/
```

I'm not familiar with Oracle Warehouse Builder and do not know if this solution will work in that environment.  And I assume that in a data warehouse SQL injection is not a concern.

---

Another way to specify the partition name at runtime is with [system partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/dom_idx.htm#ADDCI2801)
and [DATAOBJ_TO_PARTITION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions047.htm#SQLRF20028) .

```
create table tmp_loading_table (
  etl_source_system_fk number not null enable,
  object_id number not null enable,
  object_name varchar2(30) not null enable
)
PARTITION BY SYSTEM
(
  PARTITION ess1,
  PARTITION ess2
);

declare
    v_object_id number;
begin
    select object_id
    into v_object_id
    from dba_objects
    where object_name = 'TMP_LOADING_TABLE'
        and subobject_name = 'ESS1';

    insert into tmp_loading_table
    partition (dataobj_to_partition (tmp_loading_table, v_object_id))
    values (1, 2, 'A');
end;
/
```

The huge disadvantage of this method is that every DML must reference the partition:

```
insert into tmp_loading_table
values (1, 2, 'A');

ORA-14701: partition-extended name or bind variable must be used for DMLs on tables partitioned by the System method
```

I've never heard of anyone using this feature.  And in my experience Oracle data cartridge is buggy.  How's that dynamic SQL looking now?   :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I only want to use dynamic SQL as a last resort because this will make thinks with OWB way more complicated. It's a shame that the PARTITION FOR syntax doesn't work :-(